# Is there a trick in the Hunt-The-Pixel sections of Metroid: Other M

Tags: metroid-other-m

Is there some sort of trick to know where to look or what to look for during the hunt-the-pixel parts of Metroid: Other M?

These "Hunt the Pixel" sections are annoying me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best advice is to look for something that's a different color... or that looks out of place.

Other than that, you need to tell us which one you need help with.

Comment: Aww... Bah! ` `